# Add tween to scene but do not play it inmediately

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm adding tweens to scene using `scene.add.tween({config})` and the added tween plays automatically. How can I prevent this?

```js
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 200 }
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.setBaseURL('http://labs.phaser.io');

        this.load.image('logo', 'assets/sprites/phaser3-logo.png');
    }

    function create ()
    {
        var logo = this.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, 'logo');
        
        var tween_logo = this.add.tween({
          targets: logo,
          duration: 1000,
          scale: 2,
          ease: 'Linear',
          yoyo: true,
          repeat: -1
        });
        


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/photonstorm/phaser@3.18.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shall this help you ? https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/tween/

Answer (score 0):

In your tween config add the paused property and set it to true.

So, your tween config would be:

```js
var tween_logo = this.add.tween({
  targets: logo,
  duration: 1000,
  paused: true,
  scale: 2,
  ease: 'Linear',
  yoyo: true,
  repeat: -1
});
```

[Here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Tweens.html#.TweenDataConfig) is a link to the docs for the config to see other properties: